# How to insert item which type is QString to a ComboBox in Qt?

Tags: qt, combobox

I have an item which type is QString:

for example:
QString name="Name"

the question is:
How can I put this name variable into a combobox?

I've read the Qt 4.6.2 docs but still cant figure out how to do that. Please dont refer me back to that Qt 4.6.2 docs again..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the problem with the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qcombobox.html#addItem). Just do

```
myComboBox->addItem(myString);
```

Comment: Oh my god....I'm so sorry if my question is so dumb.....
I thought when I see the docs i have to insert 4 parameters, but oh well...I'm just afraid to try it in QtCreator..
Thank you very much!!